# How to get the Sphinx results based on ranking using Sphinx PHP API?

Tags: php, sphinx

Is it possible to display the Sphinx results based on ranking using sphinx PHP API,

```
For example,
----------------------------------------------
Searched_Query  |  Result        |  Ranks 
----------------------------------------------
Sony Ericsson     Sony Ericsson     Best Match
                  Ericsson          Good Match
                  Sony DVD          Fair Match
                  DVD               Poor Match
----------------------------------------------
```

If is it so, then kindly attach me the sample or reference URL.

Help is greatly appreciated !

Thanks,
Raja

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. Sphinx by default does ranking - and results are ordered best first. (but this can be changed)

But an important consideration here is 'matching' - does the record even match the query. (which is slightly different to the task of 'ranking' which gives a score to each match, and usually orders by it)

To get close you will need to use the "MATCH ANY" style matching. Which means will only require one of the words. By default is match "ALL" - needing all words. Can also emulate match any with EXTENDED match mode, either using Quorum or a 'OR' query.

... read more about these terms in the sphinx documentation.

I said 'close' because sphinx wont really give you the last result in your example. Because it shares no common words. The first three all share a common word.

Perhaps you are thinking of the "WITH EXPANSION" option in mysql full-text search. This will do this. Sphinx doesnt have a directly comparable function, so it would have to be implemented yourself. (eg run a 'any qyery' grab, the top 100 results, work out the common words (in your code)), and form a second query to sphinx. use this second query as the results shown to the user)

[having said that there is another option, could form a query that matches all documents, and then just relied on ranking to get the 'matches' to show near the top. I wouldnt recommend this tho for a general search]

Comment: Thank you so much. Hope this would help me to come out with better results.

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once ( "sphinxapi.php" );

$cl = new SphinxClient ();

$cl->SetServer ("localhost", 9312);
$cl->SetMatchMode ( SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2 );
$cl->SetSortMode ( SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, "@weight DESC" );
$res = $cl->Query ( "Sony Ericsson", "your_sphinx_index_name" );
if ( $res===false )
{
        print "ERROR: Query failed: " . $cl->GetLastError() . ".\n";
} else {
        if ( $cl->GetLastWarning() ) print "WARNING: " . $cl->GetLastWarning() . "\n\n";

        // result processing is here
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.Let me workout with this and get you back.

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once ( "sphinxapi.php" );
$cl = new SphinxClient ();
$cl->SetServer ("localhost", 9312); 
$cl->SetMatchMode ( SPH_RANK_SPH04 );  /*use this*/
$cl->SetMatchMode ( SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2 );
$cl->SetSortMode ( SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, "@weight DESC" );
$res = $cl->Query ( "Sony Ericsson", "your_sphinx_index_name" );
if ( $res===false ){
    print "ERROR: Query failed: " . $cl->GetLastError() . ".\n";
}else {
    if ( $cl->GetLastWarning() ){
    print "WARNING: ".$cl->GetLastWarning() . "\n\n";
    }
    // result processing is here
}
```